# Scheduled Cloudbees MySql Backup

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, backup

This may be a stupid question, but after hours of googleing i cant find a suitable answer to this..

We have a buisness critical application running on cloudbees. The sourcecode is backed up properly and we want the same for our db. Cloudbees doc says:

*"CloudBees MySQL databases are backed by EBS volumes on Amazon EC2 which provides a first layer of storage redundancy.  EBS volumes are backed up to S3 every 24 hours for disaster recovery and are not generally available for customer use on multi-tenant MySQL clusters.  Customers using Dedicated MySQL instances can request rollbacks to previous backup snapshots by filing a support ticket."*

So basicly we are protected out of the box in case of emergencies, but not if an employee accidentally deletes something he should not.

So my question is: How can we automaticly do a backup of a cloudbees mysql db every night? We have amazon S3 storage where it could be put.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command line script that backups your Databases to your S3 account quite easily, and run it as often as you like. I had exactly the same problem a while back, and wrote up [this handy tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2013/04/19/backing-up-mysql-databases-using-amazon-s3/). It should be perfect for what you want to do.